# Mirroring the graph on the negative y axis

Tags: plotting, physics, symbols, homework

Another quick question, I have been trying to plot a phase plot, which has resulted in some issues.
I know that there is a negative axis which it is also transposed on. However, when I include negative signs in front of the graph it doesn't want to plot.

My question thus is how do I hold the values on the positive axis whilst also being able to flip it to the negative one. It might help to show the picture to help along it's indeed a phase plot of a double well.

Thanks already for the help!.

To give an example of what I exactly would want mathematica to do I have attached a handdrawn picture.
[image]

[image]aswell.

Comment: hmm, could you please explain a bit more what you're trying to do? I'm not sure what you mean when you say that there is a negative axis it's transposed on. Also if there's code that attempts to solve the problem but doesn't work, could you please include it? and welcome to MMA SE! :)

Comment: Hey thanks! this community has been extremely helpful!. I mainly just want to mirror the image above to the negative yaxis (But also holds the current image so like stacking it up ontop). I can post the code however I have removed the problematic code that cuts out the negative part of the phase graph.

Comment: I have attached a picture of what I meant, which hopefully gives you some insight in what I mean :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
plot = Plot[Evaluate[Piecewise[{{Clip[#[x], {0, 5}], -Pi <= x <= 3 Pi}}, #[Pi]] & /@ 
   {Sin, 1/2 + Sin[#] &, 3/2 + Sin[#] &}], 
  {x, -3 Pi, 6 Pi}, Filling -> 0]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

**1.** You can use  [`ReflectionTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReflectionTransform.html) on the graphics primitives of `plot`:

```
Show[plot, 
 MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, ReflectionTransform[{0, 1}]] &, plot, 1], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) to replace `Line`s and `Polygon`s with their reflected versions:

```
plot2  = plot /. primitive : _Line | _Polygon :> {primitive, 
    GeometricTransformation[primitive, ReflectionTransform[{0, 1}]]} ;


Show[plot2, PlotRange -> All]
```

> ```
> same picture
> ```

**2.** Use the option [`ScalingFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html):

```
reflectedplot = Plot[Evaluate[Piecewise[{{Clip[#[x], {0, 5}], -Pi <= x <= 3 Pi}}, 
   #[Pi]] & /@ {Sin, 1/2 + Sin[#] &, 3/2 + Sin[#] &}],
 {x, -3 Pi, 6 Pi}, 
 Filling -> 0, ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Reverse"}]
```

[image]

```
Show[plot, reflectedplot, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Also for this example, `Show[plot, plot /. {x_Real, y_Real} :> {x, -y}, PlotRange -> All]`